# Which version of Grails should i use?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I am starting a new project with Grails and currently have no experience in it. Grails 3.0.9 is the latest version, but I have read that some plugins are not yet compatible with Grails 3, is this true? If this is true, should I consider a previous version of Grails?

Being unexperienced in web development, I am not yet sure what plugins I will require and am therefore unable to properly evaluate my need for those that aren't useable. Do the pros of using version 3.0 outweigh the cons? Or by using the latest version do you think avoiding the hassle of upgrading plugins in the future be something worth considering above all else?

Comment: It looks like Grails 3 development is moving almost exclusively to IntelliJ, with GGTS support ending - something think about as well.

Comment: This is a good question, but not exactly for SO. It's so heavily based on opinion. It all depends on what your goal is. If it's to develop and maintain an application for years to come then starting with 3.x is a better choice. If it's about getting something up and running right away with as much functionality as possible then 2.x line would be a good choice. Either way it all depends on a lot of factors. If you are just starting out and want to learn it's best to do so on the 3.x branch since it's very different than 2.x in a lot of ways. Just my opinion on the subject.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, but didn't know where an appropriate place to ask this kind of question would be?
I would like to think that this application will be developed and maintained for years to come but initially it is a project that needs to be completed within 4 months as a part of my studies. Thus I DO need to get something up and running right away with plenty of functionality (and plenty of documentation to aid my learning), but not at the expense of taking the project forward after the following 4 months have passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to  `Which version of Grails should be used` could vary from person to person and is highly opinion based but there are some factors that could make the decision easier.

Especially I would talk about grails 2.5 and grails 3.x versions.

Reason to Choose 2.5 version:

1. Well built plugin support and a wide community help available.
2. Lesser number of bugs are there in 2.5 version as compared to lower versions but is heavy and is low in development time performance.
3. Good integration with IntelliJ idea is there for newer version.

   4. You could move fast with 2.5 due to good documentation available.
   5. If you have no plan to upgrade grails version ever in future and the project size is smaller.

Reason to Choose grails 3.x

1. Though good plugin support is not yet available, I would say you may use java libraries after all and no way blocked. Most plugins just provide an easier way to setup the library environment and some helpful tags etc which we could also create ourselves. Hence it could be a bit time consuming in setup but would be faster in development later especially when you override plugin features.
2. grails 3.x is on gradle which makes it highly recommended to be used as compared to grails 2.5. Gradle is ultimate build tool that has over come a lot of issues or weaknesses of older build tools.
3. it supports spring-boot and spring at it's core but is more diligent in using it. It gives enormous power and possibilities and flexibility just like any java project.
4. It has become lightweight now and comes with least configurations which makes it good choice in terms of performance.
5. Last but not least it comes with spring 4.1, groovy 2.4 and support for traits and enhanced IDE integration.

These seems some good points to consider while making a choice for grails framework.

In last this may have several opinions from experts but ultimate choice should be the newest but with good reviews only.

**Edit**: Elaboration of certain points which may not be obvious to all.

`supports spring-boot and spring at it's core but is more diligent in using it` : 
spring-boot is the quick start helper for any spring application and is used just to get you started with spring and nothing more than that. In other words, it reduces count of your dependencies in maven or build.gradle.

grails 3.x provide `public static void main(String ..args){}` method as entry point to run your web application which makes it more springy. At the same point you could integrate any customisation required. You could run web application like a normal java/groovy main application. By diligent, I mean that things has been integrated carefully this time and not like old buggy grails version. There could be bugs here in 3.x as well but it's way better than 2.x.

So when you start working with grails 3.x you will feel working on spring with same artefact level feel i.e. domains, controllers and services would all behave same as earlier but you will notice configuration level changes like yaml files, libraries used etc.

In one sentence, `after all it's spring / hibernate used inside, you know spring/hibernate you know grails more than anyone else knows`

Comment: good post but nothing related to Java security and Java 8 becoming the standard requirement for which probably 3 would be best. 2.4+ support Java 8 but ggts only supports jdk 8.25 8.31 you can't run it with latest jdk versions.

Comment: Reason not to mention that is as per my knowledge there were issues in integrating java8 with groovy. But still I would recommend doing proper RnD before using java8 with groovy that probably gonna create problems for closures.

Comment: Thanks for the post, could you please expand on point 1 of reasons to choose grails, how can java libraries easily be used in the place of the plugins?
Also, what do you mean by saying "it supports spring-boot and spring at it's core but is more diligent in using it.", how does this differ from 2.5?

Comment: @Alexjjsmith I never said java libraries can easily be used in place of plugins rather I said we can have java libraries (.jars) or springboot maven jars / artefacts rather than plugins and we can implement plugin like stuff by our own. If you read plug + in i.e. good support for plugging in some feature not more than that, you will understand that plugins are just another layer over libraries to quickly integrate or auto integrate on running some external command. e.g., in spring-security plugin we run a command line spring `grails s2-quickstart com.app User Role`.See my edit above for rest.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Grails as well. Just started to learn and doing a project for the past 5-6 weeks. I'm using 2.4 and still finding that some useful plugins are not compatible. Also a lot of books and documentations are done with 2.3. I'm thinking about redoing my project in 2.3 to make my life a bit easier.

Yes, as @vahid mentioned, good for learning. I first need to figure how Grails work with good examples.

Comment: For the sake of learning is fine. Personally I would go look at what's changed in 2.4 which is a lot introduction of groovy 2.3  which is compatible with jdk8 for a start before making the change. Look into security issues of jdk7 specially around cryptography vulnerabilities. If none of that is important do as you please

Comment: @monty_bean Kindly post an answer in answer. What you have mentioned here could have been good in comments as it's not solving the question author's problem i.e. "Which version of grails to use."